# AWS Data Pipeline DynamoDB to S3 to Redshift including JsonPaths

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, amazon-sns, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm aware of the standard COPY from DynamoDB to Redshift, but that only works for schemas without Maps and Lists. I have several ddb tables with maps and lists and I need to use jsonpaths to do the import to Redshift.

So my question is, can I schedule a backup from DynamoDB to S3, then when the backup is complete, run the import to Redshift including the jsonpaths config? I imagine this is a two-phase process. Or can I create a single Data Pipeline that does the backup and the import?

Alternatively, is there a task-runner I can use AWS or would I need to hook up an event (SNS) to notify the import that the backup is complete?

Comment: Data pipeline..

Comment: Yes, but how can you combine the execution of a backup and an import?

Answer (score 0):

AWS now has a few services that can run tasks. You could manage your import workflow using [AWS step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/). [AWS Lambda functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) corresponding to each step in your import workflow could spawn [AWS Batch jobs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/jobs.html), where the first job would backup your DynamoDB table to S3, and the second job would import to Redshift using the jsonpaths config.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a Dynamo to RS copy but the schemas of both have to match exactly AFAIK(I have'nt tried this yet)

However you can set up two/single pipeline to setup a backup from DDB to S3 and from S3 to RS. DDB takes backup as JSON objects so you will need jsonpath config to insert into your RS

Example 
col1 (number) - 0
col2 (String) - x
your backup would look like { "col1":{"n":"0"},"col2":{"s":"x"}}
your jsonpath to get 0 should be like $.col1.n

You can use Data pipelines predefined templates if you setup 2 pipelines, but you have to build your own or start with a template  and build on it if you want to use one pipeline

You can hook up an snsAlarm on Failure or Success of the pipeline.